# jsGanttImproved arrow highlighting

Tags: javascript, angular, gantt-chart

Is there a way to highlight the arrows when they are hovered over in jsGanttImproved so that the connections can be easily understood. 
In case of complex Gantt charts, with a large dataset and dependencies, it becomes difficult to follow the links.
https://jsganttimproved.github.io/jsgantt-improved/

Any help would be much appreciated